# get partial result in foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, foreach

With below code

```
foreach($dom as $result){
echo $result;
}
```

I got the result like this

```
title
description

title
description

title
description
```

Where title are links, how can I get the url of the first item?

Comment: Use a DOM parser such as `DOMDocument` to parse the first `$result`, and extract the `href` attribute from it.

Comment: @Barmar I can extract the links but how to get first item in foreach?

Comment: Use `$dom[0]` to get the first item.

Comment: @Barmar like this?foreach($dom[0] as $result){
echo $result;
}

Comment: @Barmar is there any built in function in php to get the first result only? I'm new to php..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the first element of the array like this:

```
echo $dom[0];
```

You don't need a loop if you just want one specific thing, loops are for when you want to repeat something.